# Google Apps Script - Can I modify one option of an embedded chart and preserve the other options?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, charts

I am trying to create a function (ultimately a menu button) that automatically resizes all the charts in a Sheet to a defined render width. I want to keep the other chart options (which might have changed from their default values before running this function) intact.

My code so far:

```
function resizeCharts() {
  var newWidth = 1000;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetCharts = currentSheet.getCharts();

  for (var i = 0; i < sheetCharts.length; i++) {
    var modifiedChart = sheetCharts[i].modify();
    modifiedChart = modifiedChart.setOption('width', newWidth).build();
    currentSheet.updateChart(modifiedChart);
  }
}
```

This code will adjust the width of the chart, but it changes the other options (e.g. series colors, axis formats), which I don't want.

Is there a way to preserve all the existing options of a chart except for the one I want to change?

Comment: I just ran a quick test and am not getting a change in series color or any other attribute. With your exact code. Do you have a sample spreadsheet you can share that reproduces this issue?

Comment: I just ran too. I found if I changed the `Fill color` property then it remained, but if I changed the `Line color` property then it was reset. (I used Column Chart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you just need to update chart's size or position, there is [Advanced Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) and specific [UpdateEmbeddedObjectPosition](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateEmbeddedObjectPositionRequest) request for that (which is not available via built-in [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)).

Example:

```
// your spreadsheet id
let ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();

// get all charts from sheet (replace 'YOUR_SHEET_TITLE')
let charts = Sheets.Spreadsheets
  .get(ssId)
  .sheets
  .filter(sheet => sheet.properties.title === 'YOUR_SHEET_TITLE')[0]
  .charts;

// array of requests
let requests = [];

// loop charts array
charts.forEach(chart => {

  // create request for each chart
  let request = {
    updateEmbeddedObjectPosition: {
      objectId: chart.chartId,
      newPosition: {
        overlayPosition: {
          widthPixels: 1000 // specify your width
        }
      },
      fields: 'widthPixels' // list fields you want to update
    }
  };
    
  // push request to array
  requests.push(request);

});


// send requests at once
// this may allow to improve script performance
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, ssId);
```

References:

- [Updating Spreadsheets - Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate#apps-script)
- [Updating Spreadsheets - Field masks](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate#field_masks)
- [UpdateEmbeddedObjectPositionRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateEmbeddedObjectPositionRequest)

  - [EmbeddedObjectPosition](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#EmbeddedObjectPosition)

    - [OverlayPosition](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#OverlayPosition)

Comment: Thanks! I need to spend some more time understanding the Advances Sheets Service, but it looks like this approach solves my initial problem!

Comment: @MC3 check [documentation for Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced): `Advanced services are essentially thin wrappers around those Google APIs.` So if you don't see any API functionality you expect to see in built-in service, worth to check advanced, as it may have it, because of the name .. and charts manipulation is one of scenarios when you need it